# Removing Plugin Repository sites that fail to load

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

New here & to QGIS. Loading several plugins I noted that several sites seem to not load ( example "catais.org" or "GIS-LAB.info". Cannot actually find this site(s), I assume they are defunct, however in browsing I note that some sites are up/down for whatever reasons. Suggestions on removing or repopulating/refreshing the repositories list.

Terence

QGIS 1.8.0
OS X 10.8.3

Comment: yes a good question as it is a mild annoyance.

Comment: Just do not add 3rd party repos or disable some of them. I assume you have't installed anything from these repos so why did you enable them?

Answer (score 4):

As far as i know most of the third-party plugins have been moved to the main QGIS plugin hub (unless you're looking for something very special). This is an intended choice and you will certainly have no problems if you disable the other repositories. Newer QGIS versions (QGIS dev) will ship with just the official repository by default.

So disable the dead-servers in the python plugin download tool (Edit Button) and just add this one here (Add... Button ).

Name: QGIS Official Repository
URL: http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/plugins.xml

Comment: Thanks for taking the time with a basic question. In regards to the comment from SS_Rebelious, I was investigation all things QGIS.